# Grouped UITableView with custom cells / custom background images

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a custom UITableViewCell. The xib file looks like this:

[image]

The cell can be opened and closed by selecting it. When the cell is closed, only the Title Label and the Top Background Image are visible. Here is what the table view looks like on the simulator, open and closed:

[image]
[image]

I am trying to figure out how to deal with the rounded corners. Currently, I am checking to see if the cell is the first, last or a middle cell, and applying a mask:

```
if (row == 0)
{
    // Create the path (with only the top corners rounded)
    UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:cell.titleBackgroundImageView.bounds
                                                   byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerTopRight)
                                                         cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(10.0, 10.0)];

    // Create the shape layer and set its path
    CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    maskLayer.frame = cell.titleBackgroundImageView.bounds;
    maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;

    // Set the newly created shape layer as the mask for the image view's layer
    cell.titleBackgroundImageView.layer.mask = maskLayer;
    cell.bodyBackgroundImageView.layer.mask = nil;
}
else if ((row + 1) == [itemsForSection count])
{
    // Create the path (with only the bottom corners rounded)
    UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:cell.titleBackgroundImageView.bounds
                                                   byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerBottomLeft | UIRectCornerBottomRight)
                                                         cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(10.0, 10.0)];
    CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];

    // Create the shape layer and set its path
    BOOL isOpened = [[[self.cellOpenedStatusMutableDictionary objectForKey:sectionTitle] objectAtIndex:row] boolValue];
    if (isOpened)
    {
        cell.titleBackgroundImageView.layer.mask = nil;
    }
    else
    {
        maskLayer.frame = cell.titleBackgroundImageView.bounds;
        maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;        
        cell.titleBackgroundImageView.layer.mask = maskLayer;
    }
        // Create the path (with only the bottom corners rounded)
    maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:cell.bodyBackgroundImageView.bounds
                                     byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerBottomLeft | UIRectCornerBottomRight)
                                           cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(10.0, 10.0)];

    // Create the shape layer and set its path
    maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    maskLayer.frame = cell.titleBackgroundImageView.bounds;
    maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;

    cell.bodyBackgroundImageView.layer.mask = maskLayer;
}
else
{
    cell.titleBackgroundImageView.layer.mask = nil;
    cell.bodyBackgroundImageView.layer.mask = nil;
}
```

But as you can see, it doesn't quite work for the bottom cell - the border of the table view is obscured.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like all you need is to set the separator style of the table view to “Single Line” (`UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine`) instead of “Single Line Etched”.